# what is the best way to add an upvoting function to django

Tags: python, django

I would appreciate if any one could help me out as i'm new to learning python django.

This is my code,
i would like someone to give me help, with implementing the best way to add an upvoting function to my code.

I would like the user to vote on the post and show the count for each post on index page and detail page

one vote per user.

This is my code:

**views**

```
def index(request):
    links = Link.objects.order_by('-posted')[:10]
    context = {'links': links}
    return render(request, 'links/index.html', context)


def detail(request, link_id):
    link = get_object_or_404(Link, pk=link_id)
    return render(request, 'links/detail.html', {'link': link})
```

**Models**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Link(models.Model):
    submitter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    edited = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Vote(models.Model):
    link = models.ForeignKey(Link, related_name='link_votes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    voter = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='link_voter', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.link.title
```

**urls**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'links'

urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /links/
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /links/5/
    path('<int:link_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /links/5/vote/
    # path('<int:link_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

**index page**

```
{% if links %}
    <ol>
    {% for link in links %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'links:detail' link.id %}">{{ link.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ol>
{% else %}
    <p>No links are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

Reddit Style Voting for any Model with Django-voting

http://code.google.com/p/django-voting/wiki/RedditStyleVoting

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however i'm looking to learn from how and why someone else would place the code. I am looking to learn and not really build a working app at moment. Just would like to learn from some snippets of code to see what i should be writing and where to place it.

Comment: I think the article is pretty much helpful for a beginner too.